# calling function a certain number of times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python.

I want one function to loop over the other a specified number of times, so the result is updated each time.

I have tried passing the first_variable to the outer_function(), doing something to it in that function, then passing the result (second_variable) to the inner_function and looping over this a certain number of times.

Please help.

```
def inputdata():
    global first_variable
    x = "a"
    y = "b"
    first_variable = x + y
    return first_variable
inputdata()

def outer_function(first_variable):

    second_variable = first_variable + "something"

    def inner_function(second_variable):
        for i in range(3):
            first_variable = outer_function(first_variable)
            print(first_variable)
            return first_variable

    inner_function(second_variable)

    return first_variable

outer_function(first_variable)
```

Comment: If you want `first_variable` to be global, then every function that modifies it must declare it `global` as well. Otherwise Python will create a local variable within the function, and it will go out of scope when the function returns.  In this case, you need to add a global declaration to `inner_function`.

Comment: @WithRegards why are you calling the outer_function within the inner_function? This is causing a recursion error :RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison... Could you explain what sort of output you desire from your code..

Comment: thank you all for your replies, yes I don't know how to solve the RecursionError problem.  I tried to do this by setting a limit using "for i in range(3)".  Is there another way to set a limit, that works?

Comment: @Yatin, I want one function to loop over the other a specified number of times, so the result is updated each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the datatype of your variable, in python you have mutable and inmutable datatypes,more info here https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-functions-modify-lists-dictionaries-python/

To answer you question, you should use 
   global first variable 
inside your function if the variable you want to modify it's not a list or dictionary

According to the comments this match your desired output of absomethingabsomethingabsomethingabsomething

```
def inputdata(x,y):
    return x+y

def outer_function(first_variable, something, times = 3):

    second_variable = first_variable + something
    aux = second_variable
    i = 0
    while i < times:
        second_variable = second_variable + aux
        i = i + 1

    return second_variable

if __name__ == "__main__":
    first_variable = inputdata("a","b")
    first_variable = outer_function(first_variable,"something")
    print(first_variable)
```

Comment: Hi @altdave, this solves the first problem (thank you!) but not the RecursionError problem.  Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: To use recursion you need a base case, which you don't have. Do you need to use recursion for any specific reason? Maybe an iterative solution is a better approach if you only need it 3 times.

Comment: Also i should add, using global variables is considered a bad practice in many cases.

Comment: Hi @altdave, I don't need to use recursion, I just wasn't sure of another way to do it.  What would an iterative solution look like?

Comment: Thanks @altdave, do you know what an alternative to using global variables is in this case?

Comment: thanks @altdave, that is a really interesting solution! I didn't know we could do things like that.  Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an error. Let's look at each function.

1. inputdata() - it will run without any problem so it will return
   "ab"
2. Next, when you call outer_function it will assign second_variable as 
   "absomething"
3. problem is when you call inner_function first variable is called before 
   assign because it has function outer_function in it this will cause error

Answer (score 0):

```
def inputdata():
    global first_variable
    x = "a"
    y = "b"
    first_variable = x + y
    return first_variable
inputdata()

ab #output

def outer_function(first_variable):
    second_variable = first_variable + "something"
        def inner_function(second_variable):
            for i in range(3):
                global first_variable
                first_variable = outer_function(first_variable)
                print(first_variable)
                return first_variable

        inner_function(second_variable)

    return first_variable

outer_function(first_variable)

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison #output
```

Adding `global first_variable` before `first_variable = outer_function(first_variable)` will solve `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'first_variable' referenced before assignment` but you will still get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison` because your code is going into an infinite loop.

Comment: Try editing your question to give some more details of what exactly are you trying to do

Comment: Hi @Yatin, thanks for your reply.  yes I don't know how to solve the RecursionError problem. I tried to do this by setting a limit using "for i in range(3)". Is there another way to set a limit, that works?

Comment: @WithRegards what is your desired output? is it something like absomethingsomethingsomething ..?

Comment: Hi @Yatin, yes I guess it should be something like "absomethingabsomethingabsomething"